# Connotations of words referring to anger

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

I have encountered four words referring to anger, and would like to know how they differ.

The first is 怒る{おこる}. It seems to be the most neutral option.

Next is 怒る{いかる}. It's very rare as a verb, and seems to be a little archaic.

Now we have ムカつく. I haven't encountered it very much, but it seems extremely informal, almost vulgar.

Finally there is イラつく. It seems to be just a little less informal than ムカつく?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

主要なニュアンスの違いは以下です。

・怒{おこ}る

> ・お母さんが子供を叱{しか}る際に：「お母さんは本当に怒{おこ}っているのよ。」
>   この場合のように、「怒{おこ}る」は、目上の者から目下の者に示す強い非難の感情。
>   同じレベルや、それに近い場合でも使われる。
>   ・弟が兄に対して：「僕は、お兄ちゃんに（対して）本当に怒{おこ}っているんだからね」
>   いずれにしても、＜人が、人に対して、怒{おこ}る＞

・怒{いか}る

> ・市民が市長の不正に対して：「我々市民は市長に怒{いか}っております。」
>   社会や状況に対して、それを非難する強い感情。
>   「市長に怒る」では、怒りの対象は「市長と言う役職における不正」。
>   ・神の教えに反する人間の行いが原因で：「神の怒りに触{ふれ}る」
>   いずれにしても＜人（あるいは神が）、事{こと}に対して怒{いか}る＞

・「ムカつく」、「イラつく」（Both are vulgar.「ムカつく」 is more informal than 「イラつく」）

> 「ムカつく」も「イラつく」も、人が不快な状態にあることを示す表現。
>   ・独り言、あるいは本人のいないところで、自分の感情を表現する：「俺、あいつには本当にムカつくんだよな。」
>   普通の人が、直接相手に言うことはない。
>   チンピラは言う。「おめぇは、ムカつく野郎だぜ。」
>   ＜私が、誰か（相手）に、ムカつく＞

・第三者が、他人の感情を表現する：「夫は、一日中イラついていたようです。」
＜誰か（主体）が、イラつく＞

※苛{いら}立{だ}ち

> ニュースでよく聞く表現：「アメリカ政府は、日本の為替政策に苛{いら}立{だ}ちを示しています」

※寺山修司（劇作家、1935-1983）は、「正義の味方とは、何かに怒っている存在だ。例えば大魔神がそうだ。」と言った。

Comment: 「はらがたつ」も答えで含めば？